# Column Delimiter not found Flat File Source

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file, ssis-2008

I'm trying to import the following text file into a database using SSIS.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1kicqv0rt5fuwy/output.csv?dl=0

I'm getting the following error:

> [Flat File Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8o3e.png)] Error: The column delimiter for try begin execute column "Column 45" was not found.

If I delete the second row in the text file, then the import is successful. However, as far as I can tell the two lines are identical. Can anyone help me understand where the difference between the two lines is and if there's some way for me to upload the file using a flat file source inside the DataFlow?

Edit:

[image: Here is what my connection manager looks like]

Comment: Have you set the first data row set as the header row in the flatfile setup?

Comment: Can you show the exact settings of the connection manager? And which delimiter are you using?

Comment: I have isolated the issue to the two rows included in the file. Originally the file had over 100 rows and if I removed one specific row, then the problem goes away for the whole file. My issue is that I can't figure out how the problem row differentiates to all the other rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to import the file you provided in the dropbox using SSIS, it loaded the data into table successfully with out any error.

Kindly check the flat file connection manager settings.

**General**
[image]

**Columns**
[image]

**Data loaded to table**

[image]

Comment: From a file there is only 44 columns available, but in error message it was "column 45 is not found". kindly check the Header row delimiter in general tab and row delimiter in columns tab.

Comment: Your comment is actually the correct answer. There was an non-uniform number of columns in the files I was trying to import using the same Connection Manager.